# Is there anything wrong in my racket language function?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I am giving the input as

```
(with-output-to-file "output"
                     (lambda ()
                       (print (append-longer-string "second" "first"))))
```

and my desired output is "firstsecond"

this is the logic I wrote in racket

```
(define (append-longer-string str1 str2)
  (if (> (string-length str1) (string-length str2))
      (string-append str1 str2)
      (if (= (string-length str1) (string-length str2))
          (string-append str1 str2)
          (string-append str2 str1))))
```

but here I am getting Output as `secondfirst` only.

if anyone know the please help me. will be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: `(string-append s1 s2)` appends `s2` to `s1`; `(string-append "second" "first")` *is* `"secondfirst"`.

Comment: Not `append`, `(string-append "second" "first")`. You have to change the order of arguments or change that function.

Comment: On side note, your `>` and `=` cases are identical so they can be merged into a single `>=` case.